# Is the expected value of a standard normal RV to a negative exponent defined?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

For context, the question I am attempting is the following from stochastic calculus:
Show whether the stochastic integral is well-defined:
$$\int_0^1 |W(t)|^{-1/2} dW(t)$$

where W(t) is standard Brownian Motion.
I understand that I have to show it is adapted to a filtration F of Brownian motion, which I've done, and then also that it is square-integrable.

For square-integrability, I got to the integral of the expected value of the function squared equalling:
$$2E[|Z|^{-1}]$$
but from here, am not sure how to show that this expectation (i.e. its integral) diverges. The solution tells me the integral is divergent because there is a non-integrable singularity at z=0, however i'm unsure how to show/determine this. I think I'm missing some background knowledge on how to compute expectations of standard normal variables. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any integral around 0 of f(x)/}x| for f(9) > 0 (such as Gaussian) diverges.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean - for instance, why is this divergent while the integral for
$$E[|Z|^{-1/2}]$$
is not?

Comment: $|x|^{1/2}$ denominator (for finite f(x)) is integrable.  Your question is a calculus one.